# What is this black spotted disease on my orange tree?

Tags: pest-control, citrus, scale

[image]

Is this mushroom or animal? I can remove the black dots by slightly scratching the leaves.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can anyone identify this abnormality that is on my dwarf citrus?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4548/can-anyone-identify-this-abnormality-that-is-on-my-dwarf-citrus)

Comment: @kevinsky: both are indeed certainly scale, eventhough it is not the same species.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can remove them from the leave then they are scale.  Due to the dark colour I believe they are Black Scale (Saissetia oleae). They suck juices from the plant and excrete a sugary sap.  Look for sticky leaves.  Ants are sometimes seen in close company with these pests.

For small plants some control can be done with soap and water but a complete answer is [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/4548/can-anyone-identify-this-abnormality-that-is-on-my-dwarf-citrus).

They are described [here](http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/r107301411.html) and an excellent answer on maintenance of citrus is [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/what-care-should-i-give-my-lemon-and-orange-tree-after-8-months-neglect/5635#5635)

Edit @RockScience feels they are a different species of scale for which a reference can be found [here](http://www.invasive.org/browse/subinfo.cfm?sub=9295). Either way soap and water and possibly a toothbrush for "hands on" pest control will work.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. After some research based on your hint, it seems to be 'Parlatoria ziziphi', which is indeed a variety of black scale. The leaves are not really sticky but comparing my plant with pictures of this scale is clear.

Comment: http://dspace.unict.it/bitstream/10761/1219/1/JNDHNN80R62Z352F-JENDOUBI%20HANENE.Thesis%202011.pdf for a good reference